# "Dependency was not found" for tfjs in Vue/Webpack project with yarn

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, vue.js, webpack

I'm trying to use TensorFlow.js for array operations in a JavaScript project. I'm importing it in my Vue component with `import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';`

It appears `yarn install tensorflow` requires Python 2.7, so I instead used `yarn add tensorflow/tfjs` to install the subset of Tensorflow.js I needed. This appeared to work, but when I did `yarn run serve` I got this message:

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors

This dependency was not found:

* @tensorflow/tfjs in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/DetectorPlot.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&

To install it, you can run: npm install --save @tensorflow/tfjs
```

In `yarn.lock` after `yarn add tensorflow/tfjs` I see:

```
"@tensorflow/tfjs@github:tensorflow/tfjs":
  version "1.1.0"
  resolved "https://codeload.github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/tar.gz/74b4edef368aa39decc6073af735f81d112bafd8"
  dependencies:
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-converter" "1.1.0"
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-core" "1.1.0"
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-data" "1.1.0"
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-layers" "1.1.0"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to a friend, I have a solution:

`yarn remove @tensorflow/tfjs`

and

`yarn add @tensorflow/tfjs`

I guess it got in a weird state when the first attempt to install tensorflow failed. (It's depressing how often the answer is "turn it off and on again"...)